# Github workflow action not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I am adding CI to my Android application using github actions. The problem is I am not able to view it under actions tab.

My android.yml file looks like this:

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ ci ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ ci ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8

    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew

    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

Comment: Where did you place it in repository?

Comment: did you place it in the .github\workflows directory?

Comment: yes.. I placed it in .github/workflows directory only. This file is present in a branch and not in master. Is that the issue? @Andrew

Comment: Side note: please don't set the executable flag on `gradlew` on every build. Just commit it with the executable flag in the repo, so everyone that clones the repo has a proper exec flag too (not just the CI). You can do this with `git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is due to formatting on SO or not, but in your YAML the properties `runs-on` and `steps` under your `build` job are not indented.

If this is the case, it would be incorrect. Those properties should be nested under the `build` job object, so it should be:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - ....
```

Also, make sure this file is placed under `<repo-root>/.github/workflows/`

---

Side note: I already put it as a comment, but let me reiterate for visibility. Please don't set the executable flag on `gradlew` on every build in the CI config. Instead, fix the problem at the root and actually commit this executable flag in the repo, so everyone that clones the repo has a proper exec flag too (not just the CI). You can do this with `git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew`, and then commit.

Comment: I put the code directly to the master. Then it was building. Also I had to change the gradlew path. gradlew was present inside the inner folder. Now its working. Thanks for the support.